# Strange Behaviour with LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am having a strange behaviour working with TPL and the custom `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`. Basically, I have an input file containing several lines.
Each line must be read, parsed and its data should be processed. After processing, I got an output string that should be written back to an output file into the same position as the input one.
At the moment I am creating a dispatcher task that reads a line of input, creates a computation task (that performs computations and writes the output string into a buffer) passing the string and the line number for each line, creates a spooling task that dumps periodically the buffer to a file, and then waits for all tasks to terminate.

I am using a `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`, because I need to limit the actual number of running threads.

The problem seems that when I have a really small number of threads running (1 or 2), the tasks are scheduled in line number order (from initial to final lines) but are executed in the reverse one (from final to initial). That's an issue for me, because the spooling threads is not able to dump the buffer until the end (because the lines must be printed in the right order), so a user is not able to see any output until 99% of progress.

I read [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx)  and I 
learned that a `ThreadPool` has FIFO Global Queue, but each thread has a LIFO Local Queue for executing tasks. This probably means that to avoid this weird behaviour I should not use the `ThreadPool` and write one myself? Is it right?
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. I suggest you use PLINQ to process the lines in your file. PLINQ can preserve order and use an exact degree of parallelism.